# how can i convert code to objective c for SMS verification

Tags: objective-c, twilio

I want to parse data for twilio url,which will be used for [SMS verification](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

Please help to convert swift to objective for following code:

```
@IBAction func pressedSend(sender: AnyObject) {

         let code = arc4random_uniform(8999) + 1000

         var data = [
           "To" : textTo.text as String,
           "From" : "<replace with your Twilio local number>",
           "Body" : String(code) as String
         ]

         var swiftRequest = SwiftRequest()

         swiftRequest.post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc4e304c952c972c26699b927422e668953/Messages",
           auth: ["username" : "ACc4e304c952c972c26699b927422e668953", "password" : "5ab5312824b1d057dea249668e2c4189"],
           data: data,
           callback: {err, response, body in
           if err == nil {
             println("Success: (response)")
           } else {
             println("Error: (err)")
           }
         })

         }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Sorry ,I know but my question was intended to guidance for doing it

Answer (score 2):

I do think it should be something like this. not sure about `swiftRequest` so I assumed its your network request class.

```
-(IBAction)pressedSend:(id) sender{
    NSInteger code = arc4random_uniform(8999)+1000;
    NSDictionary *data = @{@"To":textTo.text, // guessing this is a label?
                           @"From":"<replace with your Twilio local number>",
                           @"Body":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code]
                          };
SwiftRequest *swiftRequest = [SwiftRequest new];
[swiftRequest Post:@"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc4e304c952c972c26699b927422e668953/Messages" 
              auth:@{@"username" : @"ACc4e304c952c972c26699b927422e668953", 
                     @"password" : @"5ab5312824b1d057dea249668e2c4189"}
              callback:(NSerror *error, id response){
                if(error != nil){
                  // has error
                }
                else{
                  // has no error
                }
              }
  }];
}//end method
```